# find command + print manipulation

Tags: find

with the following command:

```
    find /tmp  -depth -name file
```

I get the:

```
   /tmp/file
   /tmp/test_file/file
```

But what I need to add to find command in order to get the following print?

```
   file=/tmp/file
   file=/tmp/test_file/file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe with the `printf` option:

`find /tmp  -depth -name "file" -printf "file=%h/%f\n"`

Comment: What is the ampersand for? I get a literal one in the output. You could use `%p` instead of `%h/%f`.

Comment: Don't know where the & comes from, must slipped in while editing the line ;) I somehow like separating path and filename, not exactly sure why, but yes, %p would also work.